# RegExp wildcard url in js

Tags: javascript, regex

I am wanting to check the current url of a page and running code it is a certain url. For the script the url may be something.php?something=something. I am using JavaScript if it matters.

Comment: This question is not very clear.  What exactly are you looking for in the URL of a page?  Please clarify.  Give examples of things you are looking for and things you are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(location.href.match(/\w+\.php\?\w+=\w+/)){
     // Do stuff   
}
```

Or if you meant that exact url (in which case I'm not sure why you said wildcard:

```
if(location.href.indexOf('something.php?something=something') !== false){
     // Do stuff   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a bit confusing but if your looking for a REGEX expression this will match on any URL. For example:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)$
```

Matches: google.com OR asp.net OR army.mil